# using groupby to group the column A and then create a list based on column B

Tags: python, pandas

I think its hard for me to explain but I will show my expected result.
I have the below dataframe.

```
a = pd.DataFrame({"Character":["a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b"],
"value": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]})
data.groupby("Sentence")
```

I can group it based on sentence but I do not know how to extract it based on the column by refering to groupby.

Expected result:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with `list` for `Series` and for list of lists add `tolist`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"Character":["a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b"],
"value": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]})
L = data.groupby("Character")['value'].apply(list).tolist()

print (L)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code gives the expected output

```
list(a.groupby("Character")["value"].apply(list))
```